# Javascript - Obtener innerHTML de un bucle

Tags: javascript

dispongo de unos div, ya escribos en la página

```
<div id="onlyPueblo1Caja">
Contenido
</div>
<div id="onlyPueblo2Caja">
Contenido
</div>
<div id="onlyPueblo3Caja">
Contenido
</div>
```

Quisiera obtener el innerHTML de cada DIV creando un bucle, tengo esto pero no encuentro el error

```
pueblosPR = ['Pueblo1','Pueblo2','Pueblo3'];

pueblosLoop=[''];

pueblosPR.forEach(function(value){
    value = pueblosLoop;
    x = document.getElementById(`only.${pueblosLoop}.Caja`);
    x.innerHTML;
    console.log(x);
  });
```

Gracias de antemano (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

- El id de los elementos no tiene puntos (pusiste `only.${pueblosLoop}.Caja`)
- El valor que va en la interpolación es el `value` no `pueblosLoop`

Supuse que en `pueblosLoop` ibas a guardar el contenido de cada div, así que agregué `pueblosLoop.push(x);`. Tu código queda:

```js
pueblosPR = ['Pueblo1','Pueblo2','Pueblo3'];

pueblosLoop=[];

pueblosPR.forEach(function(value){
    x = document.getElementById(`only${value}Caja`).innerHTML;
    pueblosLoop.push(x);
    console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<div id="onlyPueblo1Caja">
Contenido
</div>
<div id="onlyPueblo2Caja">
Contenido
</div>
<div id="onlyPueblo3Caja">
Contenido
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, es la solución a mi problema, éxitos! (: